# Is it possible to do analytics query to get a list of search terms which did not give any search results and the time when it was searched?

Tags: sharepoint-server, search-results, enterprise-search, spquery, analytics

I have a requirement where i have to build a full-trust solution create a report which shows most popular search results or, most frequently searched terms, further i have to show all the search terms ever searched by any user which did not yield in any results.

Has anyone ever come across this requirement?, or is it possible to do so using a full-trust SharePoint 2013 solution? if yes then what is the best possible way to do it? Or is there a direct **SPQuery** which can give me this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your requirements will be fulfilled by the OOB **Popularity and Search Reports** provide by SharePoint.

**Site Setting >> Site Collection Administration >> Popularity and Search Reports**

OR

**Just add your site path in front of this**

/_layouts/15/Reporting.aspx?Category=AnalyticsSiteCollection

[image]

Comment: hey cjs thanks for your valuable reply, but i a looking for some custom solution, i am looking for a way wherein how SharePoint is querying such data from the content db, to show it in the excel format, so that i can also use similar queries and get the required data and format it the way i want.